# copy files to args destination from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

When user prompts test.py -d "destination_to_copy_files" this reads the args.d and reads the "config.dat" file (which works).  I want the location specified by the user to then copy anything from that file to the destination mentioned by user.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse
import shutil

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', default="config.dat", help='file to read the config from')
parser.add_argument('-d', default='/home/admin/Documents/backup', help='destination to store files')
args = parser.parse_args()  



if args.c:
    with open(args.c, 'r') as file:
        dest = '/home/admin/Documents/backup'
        filelist = file.read().split('\n')
        for file1 in filelist:
            if file1:
                shutil.copy(file1.strip(), dest)

if args.d:
        f = open('config.dat','r')
        list_contents = f.read()
        f.close()
        #above reads
        with open(args.d, 'r') as file:
            dest = args.d
            filelist = file.read().split('\n')
            for file1 in filelist:
                if file1:
                    shutil.copy(file1.strip(), dest)
```

Any help appreciated.

If i run script I get:

```
  File "./test.py", line 57, in <module>
    with open(args.d, 'r') as file:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'backup/'
```

Comment: What is the output of your code? Where are you stuck with this?

Comment: I have added the error returned if I run this.  Not sure how I can get arg.d input to be specified as the destination to copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reads like you want and expect `args.d` to be a destination *directory* but if that is the case, you cannot open and read it like a regular file ... and why would you want to?

```
if args.d:
    with open('config.dat','r') as f
        for line in f:
            shutil.copy(line.strip(), args.d)
```

Comment: ahhh thats perfect... didnt realise what i done there. - Thanks for the help